# how can I get x11() available for rpy2 in python environment?

Tags: python, r, x11, rpy2, xquartz

I am trying to plot a simple graph in python 3 using the rpy2 library:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

r = robjects.r

x = robjects.IntVector(range(10))
y = r.rnorm(10)

r.X11(1,1)

r.layout(r.matrix(robjects.IntVector([1,2,3,2]), nrow=2, ncol=2))
r.plot(r.runif(10), y, xlab="runif", ylab="foo/bar"
```

But I get this error:

```
/Users/Irbin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: Error in (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  : 
X11 is not available
warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bdd0b9cb9184> in <module>()
----> 1 import codecs, os, ast;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/7q/2v_j6pcx0bb9jq2r_4b2b30w0000gn/T/pyDtdUIr''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/7q/2v_j6pcx0bb9jq2r_4b2b30w0000gn/T/pyDtdUIr''');__block = ast.parse(__code, '''/Users/Irbin/Downloads/scratch.py''', mode='exec');__last = __block.body[-1];__isexpr = isinstance(__last,ast.Expr);__block.body.pop() if __isexpr else None;exec(compile(__block, '''/Users/Irbin/Downloads/scratch.py''', mode='exec'));eval(compile(ast.Expression(__last.value), '''/Users/Irbin/Downloads/scratch.py''', mode='eval')) if __isexpr else None

~/Downloads/scratch.py in <module>()
  6 # r Into (run inside sub codes)
  7 
----> 8 
  9 import pdb
 10 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
176                 v = kwargs.pop(k)
177                 kwargs[r_k] = v
--> 178         return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
179 
180 pattern_link = re.compile(r'\\link\{(.+?)\}')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
104         for k, v in kwargs.items():
105             new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
--> 106         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
107         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
108         return res

RRuntimeError: Error in (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  : 
X11 is not available
```

I googled it and I have understood X11 is necessary on OSX for graphics. When I check it with rpy2 I obtain the following:

```
print(robjects.r("capabilities()"))

jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE 
http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Which indicate X11() is not available (FALSE), but if I run native R and code the same instruction X11() is available, as you can see:

```
capabilities()

jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE 
NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

So, how can I get x11() available for rpy2 in a python environment?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

X11 is working on my side.

Whenever you observe differences between R in rpy2 and the "regular R on the system", this is often means that different installations of R are used.

There is a small utility module tell a user more about which R rpy2 is using:

```
python -m rpy2.situation
```

Does this match the R that has x11 ?